# SAPUI5 No dynamic way to get form data without data binding. And no Form submit event.

Tags: forms, submit, sapui5

I have a simple form that's in a dialog fragment used to submitting two fields for log-in auth. 
For simplicity I was hoping to not have to use data binding, but rather use some method to gather all data inside my sap.ui.layout.form.SimpleForm.

I added a name property to each input element which says in the docs it is " Defines the name of the control for the purposes of form submission."
https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.InputBase/controlProperties#name

However hard as I try to find there doesn't seem to be any getFormData methods. 
All SO questions and guides either use data binding to a model, or hard-code references to the individual input controls with .getValue() methods.

And looking further into the form API, there doesn't seem to be a Submit event either.

Given an arbitrary form, what would be the best way to gather all submission values without hard-coded references or data-binding? 
Would a method that walks though all the children elements of a form looking for all submission values work? I think it might, but there are more submission input types then just the input component.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the value of the fields by directly using;

```
var oField = sap.ui.getCore().byId('IdOfTheFieldAtTheDialog');
var sValue = oField.getValue();
```

But it's always better and convenient to use data binding which keep things neat.

And If I assume that you have the id of parent form container, you can iterate over the items and get the sap.m.Input elements in it without knowing the IDs of the individual inputs, and you may check the name property of the fields if you want. Check this snippet;

https://jsfiddle.net/hdereli/9e92osfk/3/

Comment: This assumes you already have the IDs of the field. I'm more looking for a method that's at the form level which will find all the fields inside the form;

Comment: Check the snippet. It may be a solution.